# Designing ViewController with slider panel and TableView

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'd like to consult designing approach of my new ViewController.

Here is a project. Please forgive foreign language. Fortunately the text is not important. Ignore the yellow thingy aswell

[image: GUI project]

Don't bother the bars, those are just navigation bar and tab bar. What is important is a right approach for designing a table and the search panel above ("Szukaj" is a search button).

Search panel should be opened by clicking the magnifying glass button on the navigation bar. It should slide down from beneath of the navigation bar and move down the table until it's fully open. Search panel hides on mangifying glass click or on table scroll. It will slide up/down only in those situations, there will be no "finger sliding "it

What would be the best approach of building it?

**Should I include search panel on my ViewController xib file, or create and adding it in a runtime using another xib?** Slide down/up animation is very important, I want it to look cool.

What if it was in the nib file from the begining set as hidden? Would the table take it's place? Can I eaisly animate it on show?

Any advices are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say that many of us would probably find several ways to go about that but here is what I think I would do:

I would create a separate UIView for the search panel and put it in the nib in it's hidden position, which would be on top of the visible area. After pressing a button, I would slide it down (with a simple UIView's animate task) and, at the same time, resize the UITableView so it's top aligns with the bottom of the search panel and it's bottom remains in the same place.

Creating and destroying the search panel every time someone opens and closes it seems inefficient to me, especially that it can happen a lot of times within short time.

Comment: Just to clarify: You'd put the search panel view on the top of the UITableView, so it theoretically cloak part of UITableView, but it won't because it's state is hidden. On open you'd show search panel somewhere "over the screen" and start sliding it down with animation task along with the UITableView beeing resized? Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still more into Android than iOS and might be mixing things

Comment: By "on top" I meant the y-coordinate, just as your "over the screen" since it makes sense to start with positioning it there. But basically, yes, you're right.

Comment: how do I position it there in layout editor? It won't allow just drag me it outside it's container :)

Comment: Oh, but i can do that in the size inspector seting minus Y value :)

Comment: Achieved it super eaisly with your approach. Thanks a lot!